# Does Dev-Cpp 5.11 support C++ 11?

Tags: c++11, dev-c++

I struggled to find a clear answer on the first Google page. 
I have troubles understanding the term "Language standard". I mean, the new standard should be implemented on a software level, right? It's not just a list of things discovered that users can now do, right? 
I use delegating constructors, get a warning:

> [Warning] delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Though things **seem** to work the way I want them to. Is such warning critical? If so, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev-Cpp is just IDE (frontend) for coder and behind it sits MinGW with GCC 4.9.2 as compiler*.  So every time you click "Run" or "Build" it is GCC to do the dirty job. GCC by default uses C++03 standard and to use newer one you have to tell it explicitly via compiler flag `-std=c++11`. You can change it in `Tools->Compiler Options->Settings->Code generation->Language standard (-std)`.

I am not sure why delegating constructors could work without C++11 (probably some GCC feature), but for sure you will not be able to use C++11 libraries without -std=c++11. It will also get rid of the warning.

(* Assuming you used default Dev-C++ installer.)

Comment: "I am not sure why delegating constructors could work without C++11" -- GCC doesn't have separate C++ compilers for C++03, C++11, C++14, etc., it has a single compiler which behaves slightly differently in each compilation mode. When delegating constructors were added, the natural result was that they would be available in all modes (since it didn't conflict with any C++03 features). The GCC devs could have made it an error in that mode, or could have silently accepted it, but apparently decided a warning would provide a better user experience.

Comment: The default depends on which version of gcc you're using. For example g++ 7.3 defaults to `-std=gnu++14`. No version of gcc/g++ is fully conforming by default. The default for C is `-std=gnuNN`, and for C++ `-std=gnu++NN`, where "gnu" indicates the specified standard with GNU extensions. The value of `NN` varies by release but doesn't change often.